# VIM jumplist paged output

Tags: vim

The output of `:jumps` can be configured either as 'paged' output (`:set more`) or 'everything-at-once' (`:set nomore`).

But I would like it to behave as (`:set nomore`) while at the same time having the possibility to go back pages like in (`:set more`) mode, if needed.

Is this possible?
For example, telling VIM to use 'less +G' as pager?  If yes, how?

Comment: You can't tell Vim to use an external pager but if you don't mind an extra keystroke you can keep `set more` and press `G` (just like in `less`) to go down to the prompt. This gets you the `'nomore'` behavior *and* the `'more'` navigation keys.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this is what I'm doing so far, and it seems that one can not easily improve it. If it annoys me enough I should work on a patch.